# How can I print a blank char using printf?

Tags: c++, char, printf

I'm currently using the following code to print the elapsed time (in seconds) on the screen:

```
for(int i = 1;  i < 20;  i++)
{
    char cheese[0];

    if(i < 10)
    {
        cheese[0] = '0';
    }
    else    cheese[0] = '\0';

    system("CLS");
    printf("%c%i", cheese[0], i);

    Sleep(1000);
}
```

I would like to output the time as:

```
..
08
09
10
..
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Do you mean a newline character? Can you please clarify?

Comment: Blank char? You mean a space?

Comment: @Thomas: I've read somewhere that the `\0` is used for a NULL char. What I was trying to do is add a zero before the number if it is lower than 10 and add a blank char (not a space!) if it is 10 or higher. How can I do that?

Comment: @Thomas: Okay, thank you! But when I use it, it outputs a space. But I want nothing outputted..

Comment: @Datoxalas: As others have said, use formatting in printf.

Comment: @Thomas: I understand, it is working. But isn't there any way to print a blank character to the screen, like my question? I am just curious.

Comment: @Datoxalas: You can print a NUL character (that is, the character which is reprsented internally in the program using the character code zero). Just print it. But that is not the same as not printing anything, which seems to be what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something like:

```
printf("%02i", i);
```

This will always produce at least two digits, with leading zeros if necessary.

If you wanted to pad with a space instead of zero, you should use:

```
printf("%2i", i);
```

Would produce:

```
 1
 2
10
```

**Not recommended:**

If you wanted to do that without using the size specifier in the format string, you could do a trick like this:

```
char pad[2];
pad[1] = 0; // make sure the pad string is terminated properly
if (i >= 10) {
 pad[0] = 0; // plain zero - end of string marker
} else {
 pad[0] = '0'; // character zero
}
printf("%s%i", pad, i);
```

`pad` would be a zero-length string if `i` has at least two digits, so printf would not output a character.

Comment: Also, you want ``cheese`` to be 1 char, so define it as ``char cheese;`` or ``char cheese[1];``. Right now it's got zero length.

Comment: Thanks you very much, you have answered both of my questions!

Answer (score 3):

```
for(int i = 1;  i < 20;  i++)
{
    system("CLS");
    printf("%02d", i);

    Sleep(1000);
}
```

... is probably closer to what you want.

Comment: @Datoxalas I don't think you understand what this does. the 02 in the printf indicates that there should be at least 2 characters printed and that if there aren't enough, the rest should be padded with 0's which is what you want.

Comment: @quasiverse @Mat: I understand that.. But I also would like to know why I cannot output a blank character!

Comment: @Datoxalas a blanc character is a space ie `' '`.

Comment: @quasiverse: So i cannot output something like javascript? like `if(..){ var i = 'T'; }else var i = ''; document.write('there might be a var here' + i);`

Comment: @Datoxalas Now you're just confusing me. To output a space do `' '`. To output nothing I believe you can do `'\0'` which is a null character.

Answer (score 0):

If you want contant double digits, why not simply like this?

> printf("%02d", i)

adding in a zero character for values >10 sound scary btw. (also because %c will print -something-, indeed the zero, unlike %s it won't stop on the first \0 encountered).

Answer (score 0):

This will give the output you want

```
for(int i = 1;  i < 20;  i++)
{        
    printf("%d2", i);    
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

But if you want to print out the time elapsed you should not do it this way.

Comment: your printf syntax is wrong. the `d` and `2` are inverted, and without a `0`, this will not zero-pad. (It will pad with whitespace).

Comment: @Datoxalas: Sleep does not guarantee you to slepp exactly one second, it inly gives you not less than 1 second. So what you should do depends on which framework or library you use.